# C++ keywords on CUDA C code

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvcc

I am using CUDA to accelerate some parts of a C program. This program makes use of some C++ keywords as identifiers, so it doesn't compile as C++. Now that I changed it with CUDA, how can I compile it with NVCC?

For instance, I get the error:

```
table.h(65): error: expected an identifier
```

when compiling the code:

```
struct sw_table_position {
    unsigned long private[4];
};
```

Which is perfectly valid C, but invalid C++. I am using CUDA 5.

Comment: That is in host code inside .cu file, I take it?

Comment: Why not search & replace `private` in your code by something else?

Comment: @didierc The source is not 'mine'. It is a free software that I expect to merge future updates with my changes. I don't want to go changing things around to facilitate my job in the future.

Comment: Fork the project and do what you need to make it work with your own goals. This is the very **purpose** of the free software license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NVCC compiles C++ code, not C code**. Even if it pretends to consume C code in reality you just get a more C-like behavior, not a C compiler ([see this post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/413712/-host-compilation-not-obeyed-nvcc-compiling-source-as-c-when-i-want-it-to-compile-c/)). For this reason `private` is a keyword and can't be used as identifier (like any other C++ keyword).

Actually `--host-compilation C` is *deprecated* (it shouldn't be used with nvcc) because in reality it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Just wrong advertising **C support**. In reality it's a C++ compiler with _some_ C++ features disabled. So, strictly speaking, you're not writing C code but C++ code with something less. Anyway not so bad advertising, they describe this _issue_ on their web-site. ;)